# Python type hints for Stripe Objects

Tags: python, types, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Python SDK and would like to add Python type hint like this:

```
from stripe import Customer

def get_stripe_customer(stripe_customer_id) -> Customer:
    return stripe.Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id)
```

What I'm worrying about this is type-casting error. Because `stripe.Customer.retrieve` function returns `Any` type, is it a wrong idea of adding `Customer` type hint to this function?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `stripe-python` has type hints in it, so everything returns `Any`. If you are certain that it will always return a `Customer` this is fine. What does it return, say, if the customer id cannot be found?

Comment: Type hints do not implicitly cast variables. Python will throw an error if there are mismatching types.